# Developing with google chrome refresh problems

Tags: google-chrome, post

This is driving me nuts. Whenever I use chrome (all the time I love it so much) I run into a weird thing.
In other browsers and chrome, if I submit a form I expect the broswer to then, when I hit f5, ask me to resend the data. If I then click in the address bar and click enter it does not ask me about sending data and this is ok too. The problem is that under every other browser but chrome after I do the click address bar + enter thing I can hit f5 and it will just reload the page. Under chrome it resubmits. Its like chrome remembers that I have once submited data and just remembers it for ever.

Chrome version: 16.0.912.77

Hope I make sense!

Comment: I have the same problem. I have to click on a link that points to the same address to get rid of this... I haven't found any workaround yet.

Comment: @periklis At least I am not crasy! Maybe someone has a solution or explanation.

Comment: Same problem in Chrome 18, POST data is retained between page loads whereas it should not. It is a bug in Chrome, a bug report has been submitted.

Comment: This is bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=21245 BTW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As devicenull commented:
This is bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=21245

So there it is its a bug one day it should get fixed.